# how to move 3dcursor with axis constraint

Tags: snapping

i am trying to use 3dcursor to set at center bottom of the object.
"shift S" can set the cursor at center, then i would like to move only Z axis to snaps to the some other bottom vertex.
i could do this with maya using "D" (move the pivot) and "V"(snap to vertex) with active manipulater axis.

moving cursol as pressing "Z" also could do similar,but it slips from the start position.

please if someone know other tips for this??
[image]

for now, i copy the z position from vertex first, and paste it to cursor z position.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you should first enable *Face Snapping.* Press the magnet icon to enable snapping, and open the drop-down menu and select *Face*. You can toggle snapping using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> can be used to bring up the snapping type menu.

[image]

From there, use the *Cursor* tool and press <kbd>Z</kbd> to lock the motion to the z-axis. Holding down LMB and hovering over the face of the cube will then move the 3D Cursor downwards to the face.

Tip: You can also move the 3D Cursor by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+RMB.

Comment: thank you for reply.

Comment: thank you for reply. I tried to do so, but when I press Z, I see shading menu appearing.and also I tried to hold down LMB first,and pressed Z after that, then cursol sliped by the action of holding.  maybe I should set Z key to axis short cut or something??

Comment: Hm...my bad. I didn't even notice that the cursor was already jumping off of its initial location. I didn't find a fix for that...but I guess what you could do is add an empty axis, move that to the desired location, and then Shift+S > Cursor to Selected

Comment: Thank you   I will use that way, “add an empty axis, move that to the desired location, and then Shift+S > Cursor to Selected”